# Jest/React testing error "SyntaxError: Private field '#root' must be declared in an enclosing class"

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, babel-jest

I am new to testing react components and I am getting a constant error here. It is something to do with the CSS import in the embedded component of the component I am testing:

```
    SyntaxError: Private field '#root' must be declared in an enclosing class

      2 | import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
      3 | import SearchContext from "../contexts/SearchStore";
    > 4 | import "../styles/all.css";
        | ^
      5 |
      6 | const NavBar = ({ content }) => {
      7 |   const { setTerm } = useContext(SearchContext);

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1728:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/NavBar.jsx:4:1)

      Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
      Tests:       0 total
      Snapshots:   0 total
      Time:        1.453 s
```

The error is occuring on the embedded component (NavBar) of the component that I am testing. Component I am testing (Landing) and the test:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useContext } from "react";
import SearchContext from "../contexts/SearchStore";
import NavBar from "./NavBar";
import "../styles/all.css";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";



const Landing = () => {
  const { navigate } = useContext(SearchContext);
  const hover = useRef(false);

  const animations = {
    initial: { opacity: 0.5, y: 0 },
    animate: { opacity: 1, y: 0 },
    exit: { opacity: 0, y: -200 },
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const nav = document.getElementsByClassName("navClass")[0];
    nav.classList.add("navClassAnimate");
  }, []);

  const handleClick = () => {
    const navBg = document.getElementsByClassName("navClass")[0];
    const wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper")[0];

    navBg.classList.remove("navClassAnimate");
    wrapper.classList.add("wrapperLoad");

    setTimeout(() => {
      navigate("search");
    }, 1000);
  };

  return (
    <motion.main
      variants={animations}
      initial="initial"
      animate="animate"
      exit="exit"
      className="landingContainer d-flex flex-column"
    >
      <NavBar content={content} />
      <div className="wrapper h-100">
        <div className="d-flex h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column-reverse mainDiv">
          <button
            onMouseEnter={() => handleHover()}
            onMouseLeave={() => handleHover()}
            onClick={() => handleClick()}
            type="button"
            className="btn btn-outline-dark fs-4 rounded-pill p-3 px-5 startButton"
          >
            Get started!
          </button>
          <div className="d-flex border rounded-3 p-5 pt-3 pb-3 spotifyDiv">
            <h2 className="fs-5 me-2 mt-2 powered">Powered by</h2>
            <i className="spotify icon fs-1 spotifyNav"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </motion.main>
  );
};
```

Component where the error is occuring:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import SearchContext from "../contexts/SearchStore";
import "../styles/all.css";

const NavBar = ({ content }) => {
  const { setTerm } = useContext(SearchContext);

  return (
    <>
      <header className="navClass d-flex justify-content-center">
        <NavLink
          onClick={() => {
            setTerm("");
          }}
          className="text-uppercase"
          to="/search"
        >
          {content}
        </NavLink>
      </header>
    </>
  );
};
```

Test file (it is not complete, I am just testing that the component renders for now):

```
import React from "react";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import Landing from "./Landing";

test("On hover the classes are added to the spotify div", () => {
  render(<Landing />);
  screen.debug();
});
```

Configuration of jest and babel etc:

Script "npm test":

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Packages for config:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.2",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.9",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.25",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.8",
    "babel-jest": "^29.3.1",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  }
```

.babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

I have searched far and wide and don't understand why this error is occuring. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue. It was to do with manually configuring Jest and the babelrc file. So I deleted the manual configuration and instead installed the correct packages and used the setupTests.js file that comes when you use CRA.

I also had to wrap my components in Router and the Context API Provider and Store.

Answer (score 0):

Ey! I discover the solution right now:

Ok, I have the same problem with my webpack app for learn jest, so at final, I discover the mocks.

Well that's my solution:

```
//jest.config.js 

module.exports = {
  //....
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$":
      "<rootDir>/mocks/fileMock.js",
    "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/mocks/styleMock.js",
  },
};
```

In your mocks folder you need to create 2 files:

```
//styleMocks.js

module.exports = {};


//fileMock.js

module.exports = 'test-file-stub';
```

This moduleNameMapper will set in all your test a "fake data" when you try to import some imports with the extension selected in there, like videos, img, CSS, etc.. you can modify of course.

With that, the error will disappear.

My full project is here: [Github](https://github.com/jdluis/cart-shop-with-tests/tree/master)

Refers:
[modulenamemapper](https://jestjs.io/docs/tutorial-react-native#modulenamemapper)
[Where I Found?](https://jestjs.io/docs/next/webpack)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error adding the extension `css` into `moduleNameMapper`. My Jest configuration:

```
export default {
 preset: 'ts-jest',
 testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
 transform: {
  '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
  // process `*.tsx` files with `ts-jest`
 },
 moduleNameMapper: {
  '\\.(gif|ttf|eot|svg|png|css)$':
   '<rootDir>/.test/mocks/fileMock.ts',
 },
};
```